# How to perform server side validation using annotations

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using spring 3.0.5RELEASE in my project.Now my requirement is i want to perform the validation to form.I am new to spring and i dont know how to perform and i googled it.Then i found the solution as using hibernate-validator.jar we can achieve it.Whenever i enter the data into the form that data is saving in one entity class named as SampleCommand and in this class i have 5 fields.Firstly i am trying to apply the validation on one field.So i have given as

```
@NotNull(message = "The above field must not be blank.")
    private Integer sourceId;
```

The below is the controller class code

```
public ModelAndView processForm(@ModelAttribute("reports") @Valid ReportsCommand model, ModelAndView modelAndView,BindingResult result,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


        if (result.hasErrors()) {
           return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("../pages/report/main.jsp"));
        } 
        else{
           ....
          }
```

The below is the jsp code only to that field.

```
<form id="report-generate-form" method="post" action="../../reports/html" target="newWindow">
<div class="form-row" style="">
                        <div class="label"><%=Msg.get(MsgEnum.SOURCE_CONFIG_NAME_LABEL)%><em>*</em>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">

                            <select name="sourceId" id="source-dropdown" class="input-field-select mandatory constrained"

                            <select name="sourceName" id="source-dropdown"
                                class="input-field-select mandatory constrained"

                                constraints='{"fieldLabel":"Source Name","mustSelect":"true"}'>
                                <option value="-1">Select</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="error-container">
                            <div class="error-img"></div>
                            <label class="error"></label>
                        </div>
                        <form:errors path="sourceId" cssClass="error" />
                    </div>
</form>
```

If i use like this the application is running with out any exceptions but when i am filling the form i missed that sourceId field and click on the submit button.Then it is not displaying the validation message.Any thing more i have to do to display the message.Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

In you controller the method that is processing the form post method must have **@Valid** annotation on the field marked as **@ModelAttribute** and the method must have parameter `BindingResult result` and then you should check the if condition like below.

```
if(result.hasError()) {
// return the same view having the form.
} else {
// insert the data in database and return the success view.
}
```

I also recommend you to display your controller and jsp file here.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for giving the reply.As per your suggestion i modified the controller class but still not getting.I posted the modified code here.Can you look into that and tell me where i am doing wrong...

Comment: You need to use the Spring tag library in your jsp page and then convert your form and select controls to the spring tags. That will help you bind your values and errors to your model attribute.

Comment: with out converting cant i do bcoz that code is developed by Web Team and i cant change that code.

Comment: That would be very diffecult. Because it won't bind your model class to the view to display the errors.

Comment: Is my controller class code is correct.Just for verification i placed a sys statement inside the if loop and missing the sourceId field while filling the form.But i am not getting that sys statement on my console.

Comment: Yes that is because your data is not binded to the model attribute object. Because you are not using the spring tag library.

Comment: I am submitting the form using ajax call and getting the response as json.So how can i get the error messages as json response.

Comment: Then you need to do everything manually. No spring taglibrary is required. You can get the error messages in response and then set the errors manually whereever you want to show.

Comment: If you dont mind can you explain with code.Bcoz i am new to this spring,ajax and json.

Comment: I can't put the code for generating errors using ajax here. You can find lots of tutorials on it on google. But as I said it will be very tedious task and I still recommend you to go with Spring tag library. :-)

Comment: Hi Thanks Fro ur suggestion.I have edited the code in controller class if loop.It is redirecting to the page.But the page is opening in new window with clearer fields.I dont want the page in new window and fields should not be clear.What to do for this.Any idea...

Comment: Don't use a redirect view. Instead of that just simply pass the view name. Redirect view will erase your data and display new form.

Comment: If i dont use the view name i am getting

Comment: sorry...If i dont use the Redirect View i am getting javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '../pages/report/main.jsp' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: How have you mapped the view name in dispatcher configuration? What is your view resolver?

Comment: Then check the mapping in xml file for the jsp file you want to display.

Comment: Hi do you have any idea on how to throw an exception if my form has validation errors.My idea is inside the controller i will throw the exception.Using @ExceptionHandler i will handle it and gives the response.

Comment: Its perfect. but you should ask another question for that. And I would appreciate if you can accept and upvote my answer now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Few things you must do to validate your form
1. use `@valid` annotation as Japs mentioned
2. Use `<form:errors>` on JSP to display errors.
Check this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-validation-example.html) for example.

Comment: Hi,I am using json response code in my jsp.So is it possible to use <form:errors> tag on jsp to display errors.

Comment: I think form reload is required to display errors (You should return view from controller). Returning JSON will not reload the page and hence no errors will be displayed